What fields generate compact projective spaces?
Given a field $k$, one can generate the vector space $k^n$ and topologize it with the product topology.  Then one can delete the 0 element and quotient the remaining set ($k^n \setminus \{0\}$) by the nonzero elements of $k$ ($k^* = k \setminus \{0\}$)  to produce the $n-1$-dimensional projective space $kP^{n-1}$ over $k$, which is isomorphic to the set of 1-dimensional subspaces of $k^n$.  Mostly, people choose the reals $\mathbb{R}$ or complexes $\mathbb{C}$ as $k$, which allows the construction to be reduced to quotienting the real or complex sphere in $n$-space by $k^*$, which makes it easy to prove that $kP^{n-1}$ is compact.
Suppose we allow more general topological fields $k$, presumably well-behaved ones, like locally compact and Hausdorff.  Is it known which $k$ generate compact (not just locally compact) $kP^n$?

There are really not that many locally compact Hausdorff fields; aside from the discrete ones, they are exactly the local fields, namely the finite extensions of $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}_p$, or $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field).

Not long after posting this question I discovered "the celebrated theorem of Pontriagin characterizing the reals, complex numbers, and quaternions as the only connected locally compact division rings" as reported in Warner's \textit{Topological Fields}.  "Theorem 27.2:  If $D$ is a connected locally compact division ring, then $D$ is topologically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{H}$."  This reflects what Qiaochu Yuan says above.
The condition of connectedness mentioned in the quote struck me because I have sketched a proof that connectedness of $k$ is sufficient to prove $kP^n$ is compact, and I suspect that connectedness is also necessary.  (Connectedness of a topological field is a strong property; non-connected topological fields are totally disconnected.)
This does explain why all expositions I have seen of projective spaces have involved metrics, absolute values, or valuations, rather than using basic topology --- all locally compact Hausdorff fields have one or the other.
